Tried following a tutorial to add in some textures, seemed fine on shading, once i went to render vision it looked like the image. What happened?
Here are the images of what the render preview shows me, of my rendering settings and of the shading nodes, in all honesty any of these or all of them could be the problem





Blender file

Do you have any lights in your scene?

Yes, and i tried different options, point, sun, cone, plane, changing the strengh, removing the cube, putting them outside the cube, or inside, and it still looked like this

I think we'll need to see your Blend file in that case. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the full link into it. If you have any external textures, pack them into the blend file before sharing it via File > External Data > Pack Resources.

The Blend should be available for download  now

The shader view uses Material Preview using Eevee which has its own built-in HDRI lighting. You are using the Cycles render engine and both of your lights are behind your objects in camera/rendered view so the only lighting is indirect through the doorway from the Point.001 light. I've moved your other Point Point light in front of your scene and increased its power to 2000 to get the camera and rendered view below but you'll probably want to experiment further with lighting to get the result you want.

The image you show in your question obviously shows the outside of your Cube.001 object and the lights are inside it so it will be black.

Ah, i see, i might have picken a tutorial that was using eevee and didnt notice then, thanks for the help, have a good day

No problem. In future it would help if you could add a link to the tutorial you are following into your question (assuming it's a free one).
